# i want to choose and send file with actionscript with android device

Tags: php, android, actionscript-3, flash

i want to select a local file from android device and send or upload it to a server by using actionscript 3 and using animate cc. Also i want to use this in an android application.

The code below works in my computer but it gives error and quit on Android device... 
Is there anyone who can help me?

My AS3 code

```
package {

import flash.display.*; 
import flash.events.*; 
import flash.text.*; 
import flash.net.FileReference; 
import flash.net.FileReferenceList; 
import flash.net.FileFilter; 
import flash.net.URLRequest; 
import flash.utils.Timer; 
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class Uploader extends MovieClip {

    var file:FileReference; 
    var filefilters:Array; 
    var req:URLRequest; 
    var tm:Timer; 
    var speed:Number = 0; 
    var currbytes:Number = 0; 
    var lastbytes:Number = 0; 

    public function Uploader()
    { 
        req = new URLRequest(); 
        req.url = ( stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f )? stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f : "dev.cbesslabs.com/flashtuts/flash_uploader/upload.php";

        file = new FileReference(); 
        setup( file ); 
        select_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, browse ); 
        progress_mc.bar.scaleX = 0; tm = new Timer( 1000 ); 
        tm.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, updateSpeed ); 
        cancel_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, cancelUpload ); 
        cancel_btn.visible = false; 
    } 

    public function browse( e:MouseEvent )
    { 
        filefilters = [ new FileFilter('Images', '*.jpg') ]; // add other file filters 
        file.browse( filefilters ); 
    }

    private function setup( file:FileReference )
    { 
        file.addEventListener( Event.CANCEL, cancel_func ); 
        file.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, complete_func ); 
        file.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, io_error ); 
        file.addEventListener( Event.OPEN, open_func ); 
        file.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress_func ); 
        file.addEventListener( Event.SELECT, selectHandler ); 
        file.addEventListener( DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, show_message );  
    } 

    private function cancel_func( e:Event ){ trace( 'canceled !' ); }

    private function complete_func( e:Event ){ trace( 'complete !' ); } 

    private function io_error( e:IOErrorEvent )
    { 
        var tf = new TextFormat(); 
        tf.color = 0xff0000; label_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; 
        label_txt.text = 'The file could not be uploaded.'; 
        tm.stop(); 
        cancel_btn.visible = false; select_btn.visible = true; 
    }

    private function open_func( e:Event )
    { 
        //trace( 'opened !' ); 
        tm.start(); 
        cancel_btn.visible = true; select_btn.visible = false; 
    }

    private function progress_func( e:ProgressEvent )
    { 
        progress_mc.bar.scaleX = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal; 
        var tf = new TextFormat(); 
        tf.color = 0x000000; 
        label_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; 
        label_txt.text = Math.round( (e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal)*100)+'% uploaded '+speed+' kb/s'; 
        currbytes = e.bytesLoaded; 
    }

    private function selectHandler( e:Event ) { file.upload( req ); } 

    private function show_message( e:DataEvent )
    { 
        tm.stop(); 
        var tf = new TextFormat(); 
        if( e.data == 'ok' )
        { 
            tf.color = 0x009900; 
            label_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; 
            label_txt.text = 'The file has been uploaded.'; 
        } 
        else if( e.data == 'error')
        { tf.color = 0xff0000; label_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; label_txt.text = 'The file could not be uploaded.'; } 

    }

    private function updateSpeed( e:TimerEvent )
    { 
    speed = Math.round( (currbytes - lastbytes)/1024 ); lastbytes = currbytes; } 

    private function cancelUpload( e:MouseEvent )
    { file.cancel(); reset(); } 

    private function reset()
    {
        cancel_btn.visible = false; 
        select_btn.visible = true; 
        label_txt.text = ''; 
        progress_mc.bar.scaleX = 0; 
    } 

} //end class Uploader  

} //end Package
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

$uploads_dir = './uploads/'; 

if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 )
{ 
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) )
    { echo 'ok'; exit(); } 
} 

echo 'error'; exit(); 

?>
```

Comment: Is there anything you've tried that isnt working? What is the error? Otherwise try some **AS3 fileReference** tutorial to practice loading files into your test app (ie: load image or play selected mp3). For server usually you need to communicate with some PHP script placed on yur server, so make sure you also look **AS3 server upload** tutorials. Google is good for that. Ask here when you can show testable problem code.

Comment: I found a code is working with PHP. I could execute in my computer but it gives error and quit in Android device... So i could not try with PHP Codes.

İ pasted codes below. thank you very much for your help...

Comment: To update or add code.. Use the [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42877374/edit) button (small text under the Question tags) and use `{ }` icon to mark your selected text as code.

Comment: Phew!! I've added your code to the question. Please delete these comments with code, so it's easier to read later replies without scrolling down too much. Also what is the error you get? On computer... are you testing on localhost (xampp?) or is it online server you can upload to?

Comment: i send an e-mail to you attachment with my files.

Comment: **What is the error**?.. I saw the FLA but it is not set as AIR application (just Flash Player 9 / SWF output). So when you made the APK is there a part in Flash where you made certificates and chose your app icons etc? In that area of options is also **Permissions** make sure you allow _"access to internet"_ or similar (can't remember exact name) also allow _"access user files"_ if it crashes immediately after you select a file from device.